# Calling openURL from Today widget opens the app but does not call application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget, openurl

I set a Today Extension for my containing App.

Here is the code:

TodayViewController:

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"idaxiang://action=%ld",(long)aCell.tag]] completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
NSLog(@"open url result:%d",success);}];
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{

  NSString* prefix = @"idaxiang://action=";

  if ([ElephantUtils originString:[url absoluteString] withTargetString:prefix]) {

    if ([[url absoluteString] rangeOfString:prefix].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString* action = [[url absoluteString] substringFromIndex:prefix.length];

        UINavigationController *navc  = (UINavigationController *)application.keyWindow.rootViewController;
        if (navc.viewControllers.count > 1) {
            [navc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
        ElephantHomeViewController *homeVC = (ElephantHomeViewController *)navc.topViewController;
        [homeVC PushToSpecificArticle:[action integerValue]];            
    }
  return [[Diplomat sharedInstance] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

But the weird thing is that if the containing app not open (not load to memory), I tap the cell from Today Extension, the app will open but can't call `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`, so it will not push to target viewcontroller. But now, the app is opened (have loaded to memory), I tap the cell from Today Extension, the containing app will call `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` and push to target viewcontroller successfully.

Here is my info.plist:

```
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.smartisanelephant.www</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>idaxiang</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Please give me some advice, I have struggled this problem for some days. Thanks indeed!

Comment: `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` should definitely be called when you launch your app via a URL scheme. Are you sure it's not being invoked? Perhaps there's a bug in your URL parsing code?

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation to comment, but

is this method being called when you try to launch it from extension ?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

Comment: I debug it from Devices log,but it didn't call `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` when app launched.